# Regexp pattern for line validation

Tags: php, regex, file, parsing, ip

My proxy parser reads proxies from txt files this way:

```
 TYPE |     IP    | PORT
SOCKS5|192.168.0.1|3128
```

I want to make a validation to see if this line is valid.

TYPES are SOCKS4, SOCKS5, HTTP and HTTPS.

IP is any valid IP.

Port is any unsigned integer from 1 to 65535.

Any Regexp expert could help?

Comment: What is inside the file, and how you want it stored in database?

Comment: Just like that, seems like MK solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SOCKS4|SOCKS5|HTTP|HTTPS)\|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\|[0-9]{1,5}
```

doesn't validate the range though.

Answer (score 0):

For the range check I don't think regular expressions are efficient... `([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` would check 0-255 though.

As MK said,

```
(SOCKS4|SOCKS5|HTTP|HTTPS)\|(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\|(\d{1,5})
```

If you get a full match, verify if the tags \2, \3, \4, \5 are between [0-255] as integers, and \6 between [0-65535]. Then retrieve the protocol with \1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regexp that does it:

```
/^(:?SOCKS[45]|HTTPS?)\|(:?\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\|\d{1,5}$/
```

But, like MK's answer, it doesn't check that the components of the IP are 0-255, or that the port is 1-65535.

Regexp doesn't really seem like the most appropriate way to do this. It should be very simple to just parse the entries and check that all the pieces follow the rules. E.g.

```
list($type, $ip, $port, $other) = explode('|', $line, 4);
if ($other != '') // report error
if (!preg_match('/^(SOCKS[45]|HTTPS?)$/', $type) // report error
$ip_array = explode('.', $ip);
if (count($ip_array) != 4) // report error
foreach ($ip_array as $octet) {
  if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $octet) || $octet > 255) // report error
}
if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/, $port) || $port > 65535) // report error
```